# Java Weblogic installation through Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to install Weblogic server on Windows 10 through command line, running as admin:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin> java.exe -jar
```

I'm getting the error below, what's causing this?

> c:\Oracle_weblogic\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar.jar Launcher log file
>   is
>   C:\Users\Govind\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-12-22_12-11-33AM\launcher2017-12-22_12-11-33AM.log.
>   Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . . . . Done Checking if
>   CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 1995    Passed Checking swap
>   space: must be greater than 512 MB    Passed Checking if this platform
>   requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
>   Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 65596 MB
>   Passed Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from
>   C:\Users\Govind\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-12-22_12-11-33AM
>   Log:
>   C:\Users\Govind\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-12-22_12-11-33AM\install2017-12-22_12-11-33AM.log
>
> ---
>
> Distribution Name : Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c WebLogic and
>   Coherence Developer Distribution Version : 12.2.1.3.0
>
> Oracle Home : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\wls12213 Java
>   Home : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
>
> Note: Oracle Home not supplied (defaulted to \wls12213)
>
> ---
>
> Copyright (c) 1996, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved. Skipping Software Updates Starting check : CertifiedVersions
>   Expected result: One of Windows 7, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server
>   2012 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 Actual Result:
>   Windows 10 Pro Check complete. The overall result of this check is:
>   Passed CertifiedVersions Check: Success.
>
> Starting check : CheckJDKVersion Expected result: 1.8.0_131 Actual
>   Result: 1.8.0_151 Check complete. The overall result of this check is:
>   Passed CheckJDKVersion Check: Success.
>
> Validations are enabled for this session. Verifying data [VALIDATION]
>   [ERROR]:INST-07004: Oracle Home location contains one or more invalid
>   characters [VALIDATION] [SUGGESTION]:The directory name may only
>   contain alphanumeric, underscore (_), hyphen (-) , or dot (.)
>   characters, and it must begin with an alphanumeric character. Provide
>   a different directory name. installation Failed. Exiting installation
>   due to data validation failure.
>
> The log(s) can be found here:
>   C:\Users\Govind\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-12-22_12-11-33AM.
>
> Press Enter to exit

Comment: Did you try a different install directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ORACLE_HOME argument when executing Java command at the command line

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin>java -jar C:\WebLogicDownloads\fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar ORACLE_HOME=C:\WebLogicServer

Comment: its working and copied all the files but GUI version is not started